# LDAP authentication application in azure cloud and SSO

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

How to deploy an MVC application with LDAP authentication and AZURE SSO?

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD domain services ( preview) enables applications that use LDAP ( on enterprise on premises ) to be hosted on azure. If authenticating to LDAP as well as azure AD is requirement( not sure if this is the exact use case) this is something you can look at

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/active-directory-ds-overview/